# Rails count and display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I am new to rails. I have three models tickets, tags and comments with relationships and it is working fine.

I want to display the total number of tickets in my ticket index view, but I don't know why... 
I think that this is a really easy answer for you guys...

<%= ticket.count %> says undefined method.

Can you help me or do you need more informations? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in TicketController you have something like this:

```
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end
```

In your `index` view, to display the count of tickets, do as follows:

```
<%= @tickets.count %>
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
   .....

<% end %>
```

Call the `count` method on the collection object `@ticket`(Array of type `ActiveRecord::Relation`) and not on the `ticket` which is an instance of `Ticket` class.

Answer (score 1):

In controller load ticket count

```
@ticket_count = Ticket.all.count
```

in view

```
<%= @ticket_count %>
```

ticket.count will not work because ticket is object of Ticket class which does not have count method defined . you can define count method for ticket and compute total of all Ticket then it will surely work.

I suggest to use Ticket.all.count which will return total no of tickets

Comment: Beat me to it -- you should mention the difference between instances and classes for why ticket.count didn't work.

Comment: @Pyrce thanks for reminding , anyways if i missed anything please fill in.

Comment: That also works, but wich way is the best practice way? Your one or the answer below?